# I am downloading Images from URL, but I did not get them

Tags: ios, uitableview, url, swift4

```
  func getImagesFromURL(){
    for i in 0...carData.count-1{
        let pictureUrl = URL(string: "\(carData[i].pictureUrl!)")
        if let url = pictureUrl{
            _ = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){(data, reponse, error) in
                if error != nil{
                    print(error!)
                    print("error")
                }else{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if let image = UIImage(data : data!){
                            self.pictures.append(image)
                            self.carListTableView.reloadData()
                        }else{
                            print("No image in data")
                        }
                    }   //DispatchQueue
                }
            } //task
        } //url
        else{
            print("No any url")
        }
    } //for loop
} //getImagesFromURL
```

Here      'carData[].pictureUrl'    consists of urls  and pictures is an array of UIImage. I am accessing this pictures in tableView, but I am not getting the images(waiting for long time)

Comment: Can you visit each or some of the url you're getting using your internet browser? What do you mean by `not getting the images`? The url or you mean you are not able to display the images from the url into your cell?

Comment: I check the urls there is no problem in the urls. Actually I missed the "resume()" in the above code, but cleared it. Now, while I am appending the images into pictures it showing "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: paste the Urls if you can , there seems to be a problem with your pictureUrl

Comment: Try to post `pictureUrl` data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `.resume()` at the end of your task block. Update your code to

```
_ = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){...
    ...
    ...
    ...
}.resume()
```